# Colocar favicon em diversas páginas no mesmo site

Tags: html, css, favicon

Existe a possibilidade de eu utilizar um favicon diferente para cada página de um site?

Por exemplo, tenho um site com dez páginas, quero colocar um favicon diferente em cada uma das páginas.

Comment: Você pretende faezer isso manualmente ou dinamicamente? Se for dinamicamente, Está usando algum gerenciador de conteúdo ou linguagem para gerar as páginas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se for de maneira estática, é só você alterar o

```
<link href="/SEU_FAVICON_DIFERENTE_AQUI.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Em cada página html.

Answer (score 2):

O `favicon` é inserido na página pelo html.

Faveicon da Stackoverflow

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/favicon.ico?v=dc8ddf0e4768">
```

Basta quem cada pagina aponte par uma imagem diferente.

Answer (score -1):

Olá
tente este código

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.seu_site/pasta_de_favicons/nome_do_favicon.png" />
```

dica: sua imagem de favicon tem que ter 192x192 pixels e extensão .png