# Como inserir favicon em um HTML?

Tags: html

Estou começando a brincar no HTML e gostaria de saber como se implementa um *favicon*.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15966/colocar-favicon-em-diversas-p%C3%A1ginas-no-mesmo-site

Answer (score 23):

1º - Gere seu Favicon nesse site: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

2º - Utilize esta linha de código e 3º continue "brincando":

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="caminhodoarquivo/favicon.ico" />
```

:)